# Double single-transistor logical inverter not working as expected

Tags: transistors, bjt, not-gate

I had a 5V-powered circuit with a single-transistor (BC547) logical inverter in it, it worked wonderfully.

Then I also needed a "buffered" version of the signal that goes into that circuit, so I thought I'd just stick another identical inverter after the one I already had, essentially recreating the original signal, obtaining what you can see in the image: [image: circuit]

The idea worked well as far as the "buffering" is concerned (i.e.: point B behaves as I need), but it disrupted the "midway" inverted signal (point A), which now only rises to ~1V when it should be 5V.

Is there any way to remedy this, and still get a 0/5V signal at both point A and point B?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Using a "proper" inverter IC is out of the question, for the moment.

Comment: Why do you think the 2nd stage is a buffer? and why is it not identical?  A "Buffer" is normally unity gain current amplifier.

Comment: I said "buffer", with quotes, because I know it's not the right term. What I need is to get a full 0-5V swing, either direct or inverted, even if the input is, say, a 3.3V logic level signal. It's as identical as I felt was needed: the 100k pull-up resistor is redundant in the second stage and I felt no resistor was needed on the base as current was already limited by the resistor on the collector of Q1. Turns out it is needed anyway :).

Comment: Thats what I thought. It's a logic buffer with asymmetric output impedance so it may increase voltage and current depending on I/O specs.  But Hex Inverters work must better and the 4000 series also work as linear amps with feedback ratio

Comment: Of course, but I don't have enough space for a full-blown inverter, and after adding the missing resistor as per the accepted answer, the circuit seems to do well enough for my needs.

Comment: ok, but for CMOS you cant beat SN74LVC1G04 for size and price and works on every logic signal from 0 to 1.65 ~ 5.5V low impedance. But then you forgot to define the real needs !

Comment: I have a policy of using "common" components, and possibly through-hole. I'll post a link to the project soon, just give me some time to finalize it.

Comment: Next time state all the unknowns to a design question. Everyone has different priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect, the base emitter region of Q2 acts like a forward biased diode: -

[image]

[image]

This means that you will only see around 1 volt maximum at Q1's collector.

> *Is there any way to remedy this, and still get a 0/5V signal at both
>   point A and point B?*

Use a resistor in series with Q2's base - it has to be at least ten times greater than Q1's collector resistor. Or maybe use an N channel MOSFET instead of a BJT for Q2.

Comment: nice! Didn't even see the obvious "it's a job for a FET" here. (also, throw in a p-type to your n-type MOSFET, and build a CMOS inverter...)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this circuit now:

Let's look at the input = high case.

**Q1**

- Input = 5 V
- V_BE ~= 0.7 V
- V_R1 = 5 V-V_BE ~= 4.3 V
- I_B = I_R1 ~= 4.4 V / 2.2 kΩ = 2 mA
- should solidly saturate Q1

  - but we've got a pretty weak collector resistor,
  - so much collector current,
  - so high i.e. V_CE ~= 0.7 V
- Thus, A is at ca. 0.7 V

**Q2**

- V_B = 0.7 V from Q1's collector
- since that is barely the base-emitter turn on voltage (think about the BE diode's forward voltage), you don't saturate Q2, but run it in a half-on, half-of (we often call that "linear") region.

**Solution**

- scale your resistors: R3 could just as well be 22 kΩ or 100 kΩ, you'd need to make sure your R1 and R2 match if you adjust that

  - would lead to reduce I_C in Q1, thus lower V_CE, thus better voltage levels for Q2
- Also, add a base resistor to Q2: the Base-emitter junction pulls down your A output, and that shouldn't be the case!